# html5 canvas - emulate 3d rotation of image

Tags: html, math, canvas, html5-canvas

I have an image which has square shape. I want to rotate and squeeze it to get 3d effect like on the pictures below:

Source image:
[image: Source image]

Rotate to 0 degrees and squeeze:
[image]

Rotate to 45 degrees and squeeze:
[image]

Something like this.

I have played around `Math` and tried to change `Width` and `Height` of the image by multiplying to `Sin` and `Cos` of angle.

```
var w = image.width*Math.cos(angle* TO_RADIANS);
var h = image.height*Math.sin(angle* TO_RADIANS);
h=h*2/3; //squeezing the height
ctx.drawImage(image,  0, 0, w, h);
```

But I am not good at mathematics, so I hope somebody may help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You're going to have to provide more code than that if you want a quick response

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved my problem. I squeezed my image in photoshop. So, the image became 300x150 size and looked like the second picture above. Then I applied a function below anytime, when I needed to redraw the image according to the angle:

```
        var TO_RADIANS = Math.PI/180;
        ctx.save();         
        ctx.translate(x, y);            
        ctx.rotate(angle * TO_RADIANS);                     
        var w = image.width-Math.abs((image.width/2)*Math.sin(angle* TO_RADIANS));
        var h = image.height+Math.abs((image.height)*Math.sin(angle * TO_RADIANS));
        ctx.translate(-w/2, -h/2);
        ctx.drawImage(image,  0, 0, w, h);          
        ctx.restore();
```

Now it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into a transform matrix.

Something like this:

```
ctx.transform(1, 0.6, -.8, .5, 20, 0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ericjbasti/nNZLC/

some links for you :

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_transform.asp

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/HTML-canvas-guide/MatrixTransforms/MatrixTransforms.html

Comment: Seems to me your answer is right! What should I change if I want to rotate it dynamically? I need to get algorithm.